# Regex ruby - searching the strings in an array and downcase them

Tags: ruby

Hi I have an array of words that I want to do a couple of things to. I want to lowercase each word in the array and I also want to cut off the /n at the end of each string in the array.

How would I do this in ruby if my array was called `my_array`?

Comment: You need to take the time to prepare a small sample of the code that shows the problem, along with sample input and expected output. We will see that you tried to solve the problem yourself. That would help avoid your question being down-voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_array.map!{|c| c.downcase.strip}
```

Docs:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip

Comment: `map!` changes `my_array`, `map` instead returns a new array. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21

Comment: If you just want to remove new line characters from the end of a string, you should use `chomp` instead of `strip`. `strip` will remove all preceding and trailing whitespace. Nonetheless, it sounds like `strip` would be best in your case.